# Liferay AUI validation is not showing required message

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

Here i am getting minLength message instead of required when there is no character/string in the text box.(if multiple validations are added for the same field)

```
    <aui:input name="Address"  type="text" label="Name">
        <aui:validator name="required"/>
        <aui:validator name="maxLength">100</aui:validator>
        <aui:validator name="minLength">5</aui:validator> 
    </aui:input>
```

If i use only one validation then, required message is showing. Do i need to set any preferences over here.

Comment: You can remove `<aui:validator name="required"/>`

Comment: I need required message first, then if i enter below 5 characters then i need minLenth message. @Macro

Answer (score -2):

1. Why not just write a custom validator?
2. Have you tried moving the "required" validator at the bottom?